# fail to create a string with inner properties

Tags: java, scala

I have a map prop call `row` which is `Map (string , string)`, now what I want is to add to it a Link key val to the map, but from some reason I get fail when im trying to do `s"=HYPERLINK(\"${tmpLink}\")"`, which suppose to work cause if s"=HYPERLINK(\"www.something.com\")") it works, so obviously there is something wrong with the `${tmpLink}` but I dont understan why, you can see here how I set up `tmpLink` which I checked and is a string:

```
 val tmpLink = s"https://bla.com/${invID.replaceAll("[\"=]", "")}"
                row ++ Map("Link" -> s"=HYPERLINK(\"${tmpLink}\")")
```

and the error I get is:

> value $ is not a member of (String, String)

someone knows whats the issue?

Comment: Try getting rid of backslashes, and using three double-quotes around the string instead: `Map("Link" -> s"""=HYPERLINK("${tmpLink}")""")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is issue you are facing https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6476, essentially, escapes don't work with string interpolation.

It's unfortunate but for most cases you can use the triple quote syntax as a work around:

```
s"""=HYPERLINK("${tmpLink}")"""
```

And it will work.